# Sending cookies with OkHttpClient

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp

I am using Okhttp3, to make http get/post requests.

I am using `PersistentCookiejar` to persist cookies even when application is closed, and later started again.

However, when I make a HTTP call, OkHTTpClient is not sending cookies from android device to web server. Not sure how to solve it, and if http client doesn't send cookies on each http request, i don't see any point in persisting cookies.

This is the code I am using to initalize http client and how i make http requests.

```
    cookieJar =
            new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(this));
    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build();


 client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    /** cookies are not sent to server.
      **/
```

Comment: Can you confirm that cookies are being persisted?

Comment: Is there anything I should do to save cookies. Don't they get stored automatically after receiving response. when new CallBack().onResponse() gets called?

Comment: Should I use a CookieManager to make sure cookies are saved after response?

Answer (score 1):

After debugging for sometime, I figured out whats going on.

Cookies (session cookies) sent back by my server didn't have expires attribute. And `PersistentCookieJar` doesn't persist cookies without a `expires` attribute. As a result, those cookies were only saved cookie cache, which is in-memory and is not shared across activities(atleast my code didn't share cookie cache. I was only sharing persistent storage).

Changing my server side code to send cookies with expiration time stamp fixed the issue.